# Why an expression with operator AND doesn't work in css selector

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I wrote two css selector expression that look pretty similar with only one change.
I can't understand why the second one doesn't work:

1.

```
a>div[id='nav-cart-count-container']>span[id='nav-cart-count'].nav-cart-count
```

2. 

```
a>div[id='nav-cart-count-container']>span[id='nav-cart-count'][class='nav-cart-count']
```

I understand that one is enough but i want to understand them both.
So i will be glad if someone can explain me what's wrong in writing [class='nav-cart-count'] because i've seen an example that looks the same and works:

```
input[key='something'][type='sometype']
```

Comment: Maybe because the final `span` has multiple classes? If so `a>div[id='nav-cart-count-container']>span[id='nav-cart-count'][class='nav-cart-count']` will not work but `a>div[id='nav-cart-count-container']>span[id='nav-cart-count'][class*='nav-cart-count']` will work.

Comment: @Prophet, first of all thank you! Secondly, if there are more than one class, i can't write only one of them? Because this works **a>div[id='nav-cart-count-container']>span[id='nav-cart-count'].nav-cart-count** (when not using all of the classes - only one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
span[id='nav-cart-count'].nav-cart-count
```

expression means literally, that we are locating `span` element with `id` attribute value **equals** to `nav-cart-count` and it **has** class `nav-cart-count`.
The second expression

```
span[id='nav-cart-count'][class='nav-cart-count']
```

means `span` element with `id` attribute value **equals** to `nav-cart-count` and `class` attribute value **equals** to `nav-cart-count`.
So, in case this `span` element has `class` attribute value like following: `nav-cart-count counter` the first locator expression will match it while the second will not!
To match both cases you can use the first expression

```
span[id='nav-cart-count'].nav-cart-count
```

or the second expression can be modified to search for **contains** instead of **equals**, like this:

```
span[id='nav-cart-count'][class*='nav-cart-count']
```